# dynamic ssl for SaaS

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx, devops

my SaaS application create subdomain for each customer `customer.myapp.com`. in my **nginx** i configured wildcard ssl certificate. (`*.myapp.com`) and it works.

how can I allow my customer to connect their own domain to their subdomain with ssl?

i.e `customer.com` => `customer.myapp.com`

I don't want to manually add certificate each customer. I want it to be automatically.

how could it have done with nginx?

Comment: How is a question about nginx relevant to [tag:apache]? (edited tags) - Plus: The way the question is phrased, it's about configuration. -> serverfault (see [help/on-topic])

Comment: not sure it's configuration, I'm looking for solution. Is it possible to do it with nginx only? otherwise, I open to hear about another services out there. about `apache` tag , sorry my mistake.

Comment: Then it's too broad: what have you tried already? Show code. That's why I said "the way its phrased".

Comment: I explain I success add ssl with *.myapp.com, but i don't know how to for my customer domain. because i don't want to add it manually

Comment: it seems that this solution available in AWS EC2 marketplace should solve your problem
You can try, there is some trial available, called Kilo SSL

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B08FF93M4R?qid=1598652428062&sr=0-1&ref_=srh_res_product_title


https://docs.kilossl.com/